# Can I replace a word with grep?

Tags: grep

I'm aware that I can use sed, but I'm trying to figure out if I can do the same thing with grep.

I have the number 36.508 and I want to replace it with 36.62.

```
grep -v "^36.508" file3.1 | echo "36.62"
```

it still prints out 36.508. What is the best option for changing it from 36.508 to 36.62 using grep?

Comment: For starters, you don't need the quotations. Second, that command works when I try it so perhaps your environment is just different. Lastly, the command doesn't change `36.508` to `36.62`. You are telling it to print the lines that don't include 36.508 via `grep -v` and then piping that to `echo 36.52` which just sends `36.52` to stdout. `file3.1` is still going to have `36.508` and not `36.62`. The only way to actually change it is with `sed`.

Comment: I'm not exactly understand what do you need. Are you need round up all floating point numbers occurrences in file without using of `sed`?

Comment: @NasirRiley I actually suspect that you could abuse grep (in perl mode) to replace it, with a combination of read, lookaheads and lookbehinds. Although I'm not sure if that is "cheating" by using read and ifs. Of course, it's pretty hacky, and definitely something better done with awk, sed, etc.

Comment: @Sparhawk It isn't possible in the way that he wants to do it. It can be done in your way or in other ways by piping the command but that's unnecessarily convoluted. It's better and much cleaner just to use `sed`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I agree 100% that it's better and cleaner to use sed, but I'm not totally sure what the questioner wants. (They are aware of sed, so it might just be an academic question.)

Comment: @Sparhawk I'm not sure what's desired myself. For all we know, it could be homework.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot replace a word with `grep`: grep looks for lines matching the expression you give it and prints those out (or with `-v` prints out the lines *not* matching the expression).

If you want to replace the match, then you need something like `sed`:

```
sed 's/36\.508/36.62/' file3.1
```

or if you want to save it to a file:

```
sed 's/36\.508/36.62/' file3.1 > file3.1.modified
```

or if you really want to modify the input file (you'd better be careful with this):

```
sed -i 's/36\.508/36.62/' file3.1
```

Did I mention you really want to be careful with this last form?

Comment: Probably need to escape the `.`, too.

Comment: Yes, thanks - edited.

Comment: BTW if you say `sed -i.bak ...` it will use the suffix ".bak" to create  a backup of the edited file. I found it in `man sed`.